Shell script gives "command not found" but command works in terminal
I'm using the beets cli music library management software on my Mac. It works fine in the the terminal - commands like beet import ~/path/to/folder work fine and which beet outputs /opt/local/bin/beet. /opt/local/bin is in my $PATH.
I wrote a quick action automator script to add the import command to the context menu, where the input is the file or folder being clicked:
for f in "$@"
do
    beet import "$f"
done

When I run this quick action, however, I get an error pop-up:

The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “zsh:3: command not found: beet”

I'm not sure why the beet command works fine in the terminal zsh shell but the shell script does not. I'm sure this is simple but I am fairly inexperienced. Any tips are appreciated.
MacOS 14.4.1

beet in in your path, but when the script is run, is it running under your credentials? Try using the full path, /opt/local/bin/beet, in the script.

You are completely correct, it was not. This resolved the issue.
However I do get an "error: stdin stream ended while input required" which I'm assuming means I needed to input something to complete the import. Is there a way to have the script open a shell to run the command so I can see the output and respond as necessary?

Call the script from terminal.

You have to set the PATH properly. You can for instance do it inside the script it self, or in the .zshenv file of the user who is running the stript, or in /etc/zshenv, if it should apply for all users.

That are two different environments, interactive and non-interactive. They use different initialization files.
Take a look at ZSH: .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin - What goes where?

Thank you, this is indeed the issue as @drmoishe-pippik also indicated. I ended up switching over to applescript and explicitly pass the command phrase I wanted into the terminal anyway as I wanted to have slightly more control over the sequence of events and allow interaction.
